# Set first-line indent in custom-made enumerate-like environment

Tags: environments, lists, enumerate, itemize

I want to create an environment for list items. I do not want to have these items as part of an `enumerate`, because I would like to be able to put anything between these items.

So far I have been fairly successful, but I am struggling to find a way to control when the first line starts, so that **the beginning of the text in all the items is aligned**.

This has been my attempt so far.
[image]

Note that for `Task 1` the text of each item begins in a different position, whereas the positions are the same for both items in `Task 2`. **How can I achieve the behavior in** `Task 2` **while keeping the syntax of** `Task 1`?

Here is the minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  % Sets language
\usepackage{geometry}  % To establish the properties of the pages
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%% General properties of the pages
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left = 23mm,
 right = 23mm,
 top = 23mm,
 bottom = 23mm
}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.65em}  % Sets paragraph skip
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}  % No paragraph indentation
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0em,
                    topsep=0.10em,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    label=\textbf{\alph*)}, wide}  % Sets default for enumerate
\frenchspacing  % Just ONE SPACE after the period, not two spaces

% To get letters from numbers
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makealph}[1]{\@alph{#1}}
\makeatother

% Environment for the rubric of a task.
\newcounter{outercounter}
\newcounter{innercounter}
\newenvironment{rubric}[1]{
    \stepcounter{outercounter}%
    \setcounter{innercounter}{0}%
    \par%
    \begin{sffamily}%
    \textbf{Task \theoutercounter} (#1)\textbf{.}%
}{
    \end{sffamily}%
    \par%
}
% Environment for a rubric item.
\newenvironment{rubricitem}{
    \par%
    \begin{sffamily}%
    \stepcounter{innercounter}%
    \textbf{\makealph{\theinnercounter})}%
}{
    \end{sffamily}%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{rubric}{With custom items}
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{rubric}
\begin{rubricitem}
\lipsum[1][2-5]
\end{rubricitem}
\lipsum[1][7-10]
\begin{rubricitem}
\lipsum[1][6]
\end{rubricitem}

\bigskip

\begin{rubric}{With enumerate items}
\lipsum[1][1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1][2-5]
    \item \lipsum[1][6]
\end{enumerate}
\end{rubric}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** after follow-up question. In the `rubricitem` environment, the counter is encapsulated in a `parbox` that allows alignment of the `BODY(s)` (package `environ`)

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  % Sets language
\usepackage{geometry}  % To establish the properties of the pages
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%% General properties of the pages
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left = 23mm,
    right = 23mm,
    top = 23mm,
    bottom = 23mm
}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.65em}  % Sets paragraph skip
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}  % No paragraph indentation
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0em,
    topsep=0.10em,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\textbf{\alph*)}, wide}  % Sets default for enumerate
\frenchspacing  % Just ONE SPACE after the period, not two spaces

    % To get letters from numbers NOT needed 
%   \makeatletter
%   \newcommand{\makealph}[1]{\@alph{#1}}
%   \makeatother

% Environment for the rubric of a task.
\newcounter{outercounter}
\newcounter{innercounter}
\newenvironment{rubric}[1]{
    \stepcounter{outercounter}%
    \setcounter{innercounter}{1}% changed  alph counter <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \par%
    \begin{sffamily}%
        \textbf{Task \theoutercounter} (#1)\textbf{.}%
    }{
    \end{sffamily}%
    \par%
}
% Environment for a rubric item.  changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{environ} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\NewEnviron{rubricitem}{% changed <<<<<<<<<<
\sffamily\parbox{3.3ex}{\bfseries\alph{innercounter})}\BODY%
    \addtocounter{innercounter}{1}
}
%*********************************************************************

\begin{document}

    \begin{rubric}{With custom items}
        \lipsum[1][1]
    \end{rubric}

    \begin{rubricitem}
     \lipsum[1][2-5]
    \end{rubricitem}

        \lipsum[1][7-10]
        
    \begin{rubricitem}
        \lipsum[1][6-8]
    \end{rubricitem}

    \setcounter{innercounter}{9} % test a narrow label  <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{rubricitem}
        \lipsum[1][6-8] 
    \end{rubricitem}

    \bigskip
    
    \begin{rubric}{With enumerate items}
        \lipsum[1][1]
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \lipsum[1][2-5]
            \item \lipsum[1][6]
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{rubric}

\bigskip

\begin{rubric}{REPEAT With custom items}
    \lipsum[1][1]
\end{rubric}
\begin{rubricitem}
    \lipsum[1][2-5]
\end{rubricitem}

\lipsum[1][7-10]

\begin{rubricitem}
    \lipsum[1][6-8]
\end{rubricitem}

\setcounter{innercounter}{9} % test a narrow label  <<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{rubricitem}
    \lipsum[1][6-8] 
\end{rubricitem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, but it still requires using `\item`, which I would like to avoid. Also, I would prefer if a `rubricitem` were only able to contain one item. On the other hand, using `newlist` makes me worry that I will be limited in what I can place inside the environment, although I am not sure whether in fact I would be limited.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I only want to indent the first line of the item. The rest of the lines should have no indentation.

Comment: @Just_a_newbie Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had been stuck on this for so long. I also posted an alternative answer, maybe you are interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the idea in Simon Dispa's answer to obtain a result that might look better than what I originally looked for, and is closer to my original attempt in that it uses `\newenvironment`.

The key part was using a `\parbox`.

[image]

I have also decided that it would also look nice to align the **)**, so I have combined a `\parbox` with an additional `\hspace`. This is not something that I asked for in the question, but I think it looks nicer, especially for thin letters like **i** or **j**.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  % Sets language
\usepackage{geometry}  % To establish the properties of the pages
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%% General properties of the pages
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left = 23mm,
 right = 23mm,
 top = 23mm,
 bottom = 23mm
}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.65em}  % Sets paragraph skip
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}  % No paragraph indentation
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0em,
                    topsep=0.10em,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    label=\textbf{\alph*)},
                    wide}  % Sets default for enumerate
\frenchspacing  % Just ONE SPACE after the period, not two spaces

% To get letters from numbers
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makealph}[1]{\@alph{#1}}
\makeatother

% Environment for the rubric of a task.
\newcounter{outercounter}
\newcounter{innercounter}
\newenvironment{rubric}[1]{
    \stepcounter{outercounter}%
    \setcounter{innercounter}{0}%
    \par%
    \begin{sffamily}%
    \textbf{Task \theoutercounter} (#1)\textbf{.}%
}{
    \end{sffamily}%
    \par%
}
% Environment for a rubric item.
\newenvironment{rubricitem}{
    \par%
    \begin{sffamily}%
    \stepcounter{innercounter}%
    \parbox{1em}{%
        \hfill\textbf{\makealph{\theinnercounter})}%
    }%
    \hspace{0.5em}\ignorespaces%
}{
    \end{sffamily}%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{rubric}{With custom items}
\lipsum[1][1]
\end{rubric}
\begin{rubricitem}
\lipsum[1][2-5]
\end{rubricitem}
\lipsum[1][7-10]
\begin{rubricitem}
\lipsum[1][6]
\end{rubricitem}

\bigskip

\begin{rubric}{With enumerate items}
\lipsum[1][1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1][2-5]
    \item \lipsum[1][6]
\end{enumerate}
\end{rubric}
\end{document}
```